# Identify User for Heroku One-Off Dynos

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to identify a user (maybe by Heroku email) that is running a one off dyno (i.e. `heroku run rails console`)? The use case is attributing changes automatically to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not possible, since a [Heroku Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos) is

> (...) a lightweight Linux container that runs a single user-specified
>   command.

If you try to check the current logged user with `$ id -u -n` you will have a different result on every execution, and you don't have any specific id or user ref in the enviroment variables (i.e. `$ env`) to permit you to infer it.

You can try to pass the user name/id to the app [as command argument](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#types-of-one-off-dynos) or enviroment variable.

Comment: Thanks. It'd be great if Heroku set a ENV variable for the user - maybe a future feature.